# С большой буквы или с маленькой?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Есть игра GTA 5 (как и 4, 3, 2...). Порой её называют простонародно "пятёрка". Так вот как правильно писать с большой или с маленькой буквы: "Пятёрка" или "пятёрка"?

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Олежан, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать "пятерка", это несобственное, а нарицательное существительное: игра "пятерка".

Здесь игра - приложение, "пятерка"  - название. Кавычки определяют не общепринятое название.

Answer (score 1):

Игра - определяемое слово. Приложение "пятёрка" пишется с маленькой буквы и в кавычках потому, что это неофициальное название игры. Кавычки как раз призваны выделить такое слово.

Кавычками выделяются:
1) слова непривычные, малоупотребительные, на которые автор хочет обратить внимание;
2) слова, употребленные в особом, необычном значении;
3) слова, представляющие собой малоизвестные термины;
4) слова устарелые или, наоборот, совсем новые, если подчеркивается эта их особенность;
5) слова, употребленные в ироническом значении;
6) слова, употребленные в условном значении (применительно к ситуации или контексту). [Кавычки, господа, кавычки!](http://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/kavychki-gospoda-kavychki.html)